# Jquery animate Slide left(extend) and slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am not very familiar with jquery's animate and I need to create an element which upon click of another element, the element should slide from left to right(currently hides behind another element).

Then shows its full content(like a drop down menu) after extending fully from left to right.   I tried doing it using transition effects but its is not that  powerful(in terms of flexibilty/control)

Anyone knows a good way to do this? Thanks

**[EDIT]** hers a [jsfiddle of what I am doing so far](http://jsfiddle.net/Abs5H/274/)

$('#menu-btn').click(function(event) {

```
  $('#whole').animate({
      left: '100px'
  },500,
      function(){
      left: '-100px'
  });
```

});

Comment: I think you should familiarize yourself with jQuery's animate and then come back and post a more specific question, including code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide code samples of what you've been working on? What is the specific issue you're running into?

Comment: I have updated my question! But cant get it t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like:

```
$('#menu-btn').click(function(event) {
  $('#whole').animate({
      left: '100px'
  },500,
  function(){
    $('#data').slideDown();
  });
});
```

Slide down the whole instead if that is what you were thinking.

I updated the fiddle. You had `.#whole` instead of `#whole` which prevented that style.

**EDIT:**

See my forked fiddle for a nicer solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6ETK8/6/

Or using css transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/6ETK8/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LVLXL/2/ This is what I got so far. I want to revert back to original state after clicking the second time

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do two animations:

1. animate the element from left to right (slide to right)
2. animate the contents of the element, or a element inside the first element, from top to bottom (slide down).
3. animations should run one after the other, not in parallel.

Learn about [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Then you can achieve this by starting the first animation (slide to right), and, in its complete handler, start the second animation (slide down).

By the way, it is possible, an relatively easy, to do this with transitions.

Comment: I am interested to know how I can do it with css. I actually also think that it is possible to do it with css, by using classes. But Jquery still needs to be used, or better yet js. Also I believe jquery offers quicker solutions. What do you propose with css? any good examples? the answer marked shows exactly what I wanted to achieve. thanks